# Experience with iLugger?

Tags: imac, accessories, 3rd-party

I have an iMac and I use it for development and video editing. I am looking for greater portability and I'm considering a MacBook or MacBook Pro. My other option is an [iLugger](http://www.ilugger.com/).

I'm looking for owners of iLugger to share their experiences with iLugger and if it is a worthy buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love my iLugger!!!!  You get exactly what you pay for. The only con I can say is the weight upon your shoulder, when using the shoulder strap.. Looks like they added wheels now, so this definitely is a good buy.